# How to link 2 Cisco switches + 1 Netgear

Tags: networking, cisco

I have servers in 2 different locations.

The setup is:

[image]

The 4 linksys switches are all on the same sub-network. The link between the 2 data centers are provided by the collocation company.

So when I have a server on 1 linksys switch trying to contact a server on another, it's going on the Netgear and either going back to the other Linksys or the other data center.

There are also several more switches on different sub-net and the Netgear is VLAN tagging them.

QUESTION : I'm replacing the Linksys by Cisco 2960S. I want to know if I can link 2 switches on the same side with another cross cable or straight thanks to auto-MDIX, will it create a loop ? Everything will be GE, I don't need any trunk for faster speed.

Answer (score 1):

If your switches support STP (and it's enabled) then yes you can connect them, and they will automatically disable one of the links (it would be re-enabled in the event of another link's failure).

Side note: Trunking provides redundancy as well as throughput. Something to think about considering you have quite a few single points of failure in this network.

Comment: So if I absolutely need the link to the Netgear to go to the other data center, I have no choice leaving it as it is right ?

Comment: No, If you make a loop at each side with the 2 Linksys + Netgear, it'll disable 1 of the links and you'll still have the other two to keep it working correctly.

Comment: I read about FlexStack (http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/switches/ps5718/ps6406/white_paper_c11-578928.html), so one the 2 switchs will act as master, and everything will be seen as one big switch. Is this a possible solution ?